# Creating a dynamic script from dynamic SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've searched a lot of Q-A's but I haven't found quite what I'm looking for. I'm looking to create a procedure that generates a transport script (but does NOT execute it) for two different lookup tables in a dynamic way.

I've been able to create the sql select statement using:

```
DECLARE
testertable            VARCHAR2(320) := 'LOOKUP_TABLE';
testerid               VARCHAR2(320) := '999';
testerfield            VARCHAR2(320) := 'id_no';

type nameArray IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(60);
type typeArray IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(60);

data_nameA        nameArray := nameArray();
data_typeA        typeArray := typeArray();

i                 NUMBER;

CURSOR c_curse IS SELECT column_name, data_type
FROM user_tab_columns
WHERE table_name = testertable; 

i := 0;
FOR n IN c_curse LOOP
i := i + 1;
data_nameA.EXTEND(1);
data_typeA.EXTEND(1);
data_nameA(i) := n.column_name;
data_typeA(i) := n.data_type;
END LOOP;
```

From there, I'm able to create the select statement. Then I want to use that statement to open a query, and populate insert statements, using data_typeA(i) as a reference to make sure quotes are input as needed.

This is part of a larger transport function that I'm not allowed to modify, my task is to expand it to include these two lookup tables, which may or may not exist for each transported system.

Hopeful output would be a CLOB or other text field like this:

```
-- transport for lookup 'LOOKUP_TABLE'
Insert into LOOKUP_TABLE VALUES (value1, 'value2', value3), (value4, 'value5', value6), (value7, 'value8', value9);
```

Thank you.

Comment: You realize that `insert` statement isn't valid syntax in Oracle.  You'd need three separate `insert` statements to insert 3 rows (or one `insert all` with 3 `select from dual` statements that are all `union all`'d together).  I'm not quite sure what the question here is.  You can construct and execute the `select` statement but you don't show that code.  I guess that means that you know how to use `dbms_sql` to fetch the data but that's a guess.  What part of constructing the `insert` statements is troubling you?

Comment: @Justin Cave there is also a third option - `INSERT ALL into table(...) VALUES(...) into table(...) values( ... ) ....` Anyways, the syntax in the question is wrong.